# error cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'werkzeug' when importing [ `from werkzeug.utils import cached_property` ]

Tags: python, flask-restplus

On importing "from flask_restplus import Api, Resource" api getting cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'werkzeug'

```
Python version : Python 3.7.2rc1
pip freeze output 
aniso8601==8.0.0
attrs==19.3.0
autopep8==1.5.1
click==7.1.1
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
flask-restplus==0.13.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pyrsistent==0.16.0
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.2.1
zipp==3.1.0
On importing  from flask_restplus import Api, Resource  getting  below error : 
cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'werkzeug'



tried solution , importing [ `from werkzeug.utils import cached_property` ] which is not helping getting same error
```

Comment: `cached_property` was recently moved to `werkzeug.utils` in the 1.0 releas. Which version of `werkzeug` are you using? If you're on an older version try imprint directly from `werkzeug`.

Comment: Werkzeug==1.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

by downgrading werkzeug.utils to Werkzeug==0.16.1 , resolved my issue

```
pip install Werkzeug==0.16.1
```

reference : https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/777